# Async method in query syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, asp.net-identity, linq-query-syntax

I learn with asp.net identity, async/await, and I have this problem:

I have some function for `IEnumerable<T> list`. This list I fill using query syntax and looks like this:

```
private IEnumerable<SomeModel> GetPersons(int categoryId) {
IEnumerable<SomeModel> persons = from g in db.Categories
                               join c in db.Persons on g.PersonTypeId equals c.PersonTypeId
                               where g.CategoryId == categoryId
                               select new SomeModel
                               {
                                   PersonName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
                                   //....etc.
                                   //And here I need call asynchronous function something like this:
                                   IsAdmin = GetPermission(c.Email)
                               }
    if (persons.Any()) {
        return persons;
    }

    return Enumerable.Empty<SomeModel>();
}
```

In SomeModel is `IsAdmin` as bool (when I tried `Task<bool>` in GetPermission I use `Task<bool>` in SomeModel).
In `GetPermission()` is this:

```
private bool GetPermission(string email) {
    var user = SomeMembershipService.GetUser(email); //SomeMembershipService is Interface with Tasks and so on.
    var roles = SomeMembershipService.GetRoles(user.Id); //user.Id is as string
    bool result = false;
    if (roles != null) {
        var adm = roles.Result.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains("Admin"));
        result = adm != null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I tried this write with async/await and as Task, but both my tries was false. So I thought that I have to call `GetPermission()` outside of `IEnumerable<SomeModel> persons` so I add this block of code into condition after. So code looks like this:

```
private IEnumerable<SomeModel> GetPersons(int categoryId) {
    IEnumerable<SomeModel> persons = from g in db.Categories
                                   join c in db.Persons on g.PersonTypeId equals c.PersonTypeId
                                   where g.CategoryId == categoryId
                                   select new SomeModel
                                   {
                                       PersonName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName
                                       //....etc.
                                   }
    if (persons.Any()) 
    {
        //new code
        foreach (var p in persons) 
        {
            p.IsAdmin = GetPermission(p.Email);
        }
        //end of new code
        return persons;
    }

    return Enumerable.Empty<SomeModel>();
}
```

But this is wrong too. Maybe I understand bad to asp.net identity and async/await and their use...
Can you help me - what I have to do? Because now, `GetPermission` is called too late, so app crash. When I call `GetPermission` in persons query, function is called too late (after filled persons list) too. I have no idea how to continue.

`GetUser()` is as `public IUser GetUser(string username)` and `GetRoles()` is as `public async Task<IEnumerable<IRole>> GetRoles(string userId)`. I'am sure, that these two methods work fine, I use them in other codes and no problem with them. So it has to be somewhere in code above I think.

I am sorry, if it is stupid question, but I read about this lot here and on msdn, but cannot find result. Thanks to all.

---

**Why I want to use async function as above**

I want the function there because when I make whole function as async Task, another function which call this doesn't work properly.

I have this function - it's databinding for kendogrid ():

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult _PersonsBinding([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, int id)
{
    DataSourceResult result = GetPersons(id).ToDataSourceResult(request);
    return Json(result);
}
```

When I make function `IEnumerable<SomeModel> GetPersons` as `async Task<IEnumerable<SomeModel>> GetPersons` the binding function doesn't know ToDataSourceResult(), when I make this function as async too. If can be problem here, how can I fix it? 
Please be patient with me, I am a newbie...

Comment: Why do you check on the `if (persons.Any())`, It wouldn't make a difference if you return `persons` or `Enumerable.Empty<SomeModel>();`

Comment: There was some problems with returning only persons. I don't remember why, but this helped. It's for kendogrid. But I think this isn't reason of my problem.

Comment: Can you tell, why you want the async funtionion there, seems to make no sense for me! Why don't you put the whole function in an async task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I resolve it.
An error wasn't in code above, problem was in `async Task<IEnumerable<IRole>> GetRoles(string userId)`. This method works fine but it is not good for my code above.

Async getting roles looks like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<IRole>> GetRolesAsync(string userId)
{
    return await IdentityManager.Roles.GetRolesForUserAsync(userId);
}
```

But I had to use getting roles which is in code below.
I've made new method in IMembershipService - `public IEnumerable<IRole> GetRoles(string userId)` (the first method renamed to GetRolesAsync) and looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<IRole> GetRoles(string userId)
{
    return AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => IdentityManager.Roles.GetRolesForUserAsync(userId));
}
```

This returns common `IEnumerable<T>`. At least I can use my function GetPermissions in sql query. GetPermission() now looks like this:

```
private bool GetPermission(string email) {
    var user = SomeMembershipService.GetUser(email); 
    var roles = SomeMembershipService.GetRoles(user.Id);

    bool result = false;
    if (roles != null) {
        var adm = roles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains("Admin"));
        result = adm != null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

in sql query I can use now this:

```
....
select new SomeModel
                               {
                                   PersonName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
                                   IsAdmin = GetPermission(c.Email) // <-- This
                               }
....
```

thanks to all, especially Jeroen, who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't about the async/await. Your problem is because you execute the query more than ones. Every foreach/ToList/ToArray etc. will execute the query from the beginning and will create new objects. Because deep inside linq the results are yielded with `yield return new { .....}' and will create new objects. That's why you lose the IsAdmin bit on the next foreach. *(outside the method)*

```
if (persons.Any()) 
{
    // !HERE! <- foreach. this will run the query.
    foreach (var p in persons) 
    {
        p.IsAdmin = GetPermission(p.Email);
    }

    //Where you foreach in it's caller.
    return persons;
}
```

You need to persist the query first. You can fix this with ToArray()/ToList(). This way the query is ones executed, iterated and stored as Array.

```
private IEnumerable<SomeModel> GetPersons(int categoryId) 
{
    IEnumerable<SomeModel> persons = (from g in db.Categories
                                     join c in db.Persons on g.PersonTypeId equals c.PersonTypeId
                                     where g.CategoryId == categoryId
                                     select new SomeModel
                                     {
                                        PersonName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName
                                        //....etc.
                                     }).ToArray();   // <------ here
    foreach (var p in persons) 
    {
        p.IsAdmin = GetPermission(p.Email);
    }

    //end of new code
    return persons;
}
```

If you want to combine the `GetPermission()` and the query, you should create a SQL-Function.

Comment: Second example I tried, but app crash. In the first case I tried as you wrote, but no change.

Comment: The first is your example showing the foreach spots. What exception did you get on the second one?

Comment: No error in log or in debug. It "freeze" on line in GetPermissions() - here ` var adm = roles.Result.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Contains("Admin")); ` and after long time I get only connection timeout (connection is right, I am sure).

Comment: What happens if you call the `GetPermission(string email)` directly?

Comment: Same thing - "freeze", cannot jump to next step in debug, no error.. I will try to make GetRoles() with await and make GetPermission() as async Task<>, but I think it would have no change... Go to try it

Comment: I don't think await is fixing this, you get a timeout or another problem.

Comment: You're right. Is any other way how to get user roles from asp.net identity without using task, await/async? Direct sql query to db .. or some better solution?